# How to make sure every API calls are served (Queueing Rest API calls)?

Tags: java, rest, api, spring-boot, httpresponse

I am developing a REST API in Spring Boot which I am providing the response within mostly 1-3 sec.My Controller is like below:

```
@RestController
public class ApiController {
    List<ApiObject>  apiDataList;   

    @RequestMapping(value="/data",produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<ApiObject>> getData(){                                       
        List<ApiObject> apiDataList=getApiData();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<ApiObject>>(apiDataList,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    @ResponseBody   
    public List<ApiObject>  getApiData(){
        List<ApiObject>  apiDataList3=new List<ApiObject> ();
        //do the processing
        return apiDataList3;
    }
}
```

So I have a 300 users concurrently loading the API.I performed the load test with JMeter and it was ok.But still there were some failures(not all API calls were served).So how do I overcome this?How to imlement any queue on the API calls which arrives or any other methods to ensure each API call is responded with data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you would like to make sure all the requests return the data?! If yes, you can use `@Async` and get the `CompletableFuture`. Then in your Controller, you can use the CompletableFuture to get the response. In case there are some failure, you can set the timeout for that and catch the exception to log the error.

Hope this help.

Comment: Yes I want all the requests return the data.Can you explain a bit actually what is happening in the @Async case? It would be helpful if you provide an example

Comment: I believe this sample is clear from Spring: https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/. But in java 8, we have the CompletableFuture which is better than Future. The sample to apply it is in here: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2016/04/spring-async-javas-8-completablefuture.html